# LabView - How to use shift register with case structure?

Tags: while-loop, labview, shift-register

Can I use shift register to pass data from cases to cases(case structure)?
I added shift register to my while loop, inside my while loop I have a case structure, I want to store data in the shift register from the 1st case and transfer it to the 2nd case, how am I going to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly the sort of thing a shift register is used for. Just wire the data out of the case structure into the shift register input on the right-hand side of the While loop, like this:

[image: While loop with case structure and shift register (VI snippet)]

This is a VI snippet so you can drag it on to your VI diagram to import the code.

If you use a shift register to pass a value out of a case structure and use that value as the case selector on the next loop iteration, you've created a **state machine**. This is a very useful design pattern in LabVIEW applications. Here's a [tutorial on the NI site](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/7595/en/) to help you get started with them.